# Making the Mod+4 Key Behave

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop, originally with Windows but running Debian (after some effort). On the bottom row of the keyboard, there is, in this order, these keys:

CTRL FN Windows ALT SPC ALT CTRL-with-a-menu-image-maybe ARROWS

I seem to use only the left ctrl key, so I thought it would be handy to dedicate the right ctrl+menu key to opening guake. However, when I go to set it as the hotkey in guake preferences, pressing it has no effect.

I searched about and discovered that `xbindkey -k` can tell you more about your keyboard. I found that the ctrl+menu key generates this output:

```
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x40 + c:105
    Mod4 + Super_R
```

but I don't know what to do with this information. Furthermore, the Tweak Tool offers me the option to do a number of permutations on the alt, win, super, meta, and so forth keys, but (a) I don't know how all of these names map to the physical keys I've got on my keyboard and (b) the menu text is too narrow to read the full description of what these swaps do anyway.

I'm stumped!